# Is it possible to create an XY (aka scatter) plot using Kibana 4?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I have a few million documents in an ElasticSearch index with some numeric fields, say `foo` and `bar`. Is there any way to use Kibana 4 to create a graph with `foo` values on the X axis and `bar` values on the Y axis? Like a very, very basic chart one might create using Excel.

I'm fine with sampling/aggregations of some kind. I understand that these tools won't show me a plot with 20 million data points. I'm just trying to see if there's some obvious relationship between `foo` and `bar` by creating a graph.

Answer (score 5):

To just plot the correlation between revenue and employee count I would just use a line chart like this:

[image: simple line chart]

In order to justify creating a scatter plot chart though (since they're awesome and I wanted to) I generated some fake data that looked something like this:

```
{
  name: faker.company.companyName(),
  employees: _.random(3, 30),
  revenue: _.random(10000, 100000),
  industry: _.sample(industries)
}
```

And plotted it in visualize by breaking it down piece-by-piece:

1. Start with a line chart
2. Switch to Options tab of sidebar (since 4.1)

   - Uncheck *"Show Connecting Lines"*
   - Check *"Scale Y-Axis to Data Bounds"*
3. Switch back to the Data tab
4. Modify the *"Y-Axis"*

   - use the **Average** aggregation
   - on the `employees` field
5. Add a *"Dot Size"* metric

   - use the **Unique Count** aggregation
   - on the `company` field
6. Add a *"Split Lines"* bucket

   - use the **Terms** aggregation
   - on the `industry` field
   - I like to set the size close to the cardinality of my data
7. Add an *"X-Axis"*

   - use the **Histogram** aggregation
   - on the `revenue` field
   - guess an interval, you will need to play with this a bit
8. Finally, click Apply

This configuration is pretty complex, but the resulting visualization shows a lot of information.

[image: scatter plot]

Comment: Does Kibana support any interactivity with the plotted points/glyphs beyond a hover tool like you graciously included with the last screen shot? For example can one click on a point and have it serve as link opening up a view focused in on that data point? I'm looking for something analogous to Bokeh's [TapTool](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tools.html#bokeh.models.tools.TapTool) functionality, which is basically click a point with subsequent callback.

Answer (score 0):

I found a hack for this.

1. Create a line chart
2. X axis is a Terms aggregation of foo
3. Add sub-aggregation (Split Lines) *on the same field*
4. Y Axis is sum of your other column (bar)

I don't see any way of making the legend meaningful, though

Comment: Assuming that my X axis is "minrevenue" and my Y axis is "minemployees"  (I'm looking for a correlation between revenue and # employees :) does this look right? http://i.stack.imgur.com/7UJdN.png

Comment: I'm not sure... [the Y axis doesn't really look right to me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/566NY.png), since it's a sum of # employees. [Average looks a little better, but it's not great.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/T6jj2.png) It's certainly not a _true_ scatterplot.